# How to create as many columns as the number entered on SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, dynamic-columns

How to create as many columns as the number entered on SSRS?
I need to create 144 columns, how can I create 144 columns dynamically?
Can we enter number for create many columns with use matrix report?
Or Is it possible use different way to do this?

Thanks?

Answer (score 0):

Create a dataset (e.g. `dsColumns`) with the following query

```
DECLARE @counter int = 1
DECLARE @t TABLE (ColNum int)

WHILE @Columns>= @counter
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @t SELECT @counter
        SET @counter = @counter +1
    END

SELECT * FROM @t ORDER BY ColNum
```

The `@Columns` parameter will be automatically added to your report.

Add a matrix and set the column dataset to `dsColumns` and set the column grouping to `ColNum`.

Set the expression of the detail cell to anything.

Run the report and set the Column parameter to however many columns you want.

Of course not much will happen as there is no data but it does what you ask.